# Benefit of using secure boot with MOK over disabling secure boot

Tags: drivers, nvidia, security, secure-boot

[Following this guide](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=274365), I was able to enroll a Machine Owner Key (MOK) to sign my NVIDIA (proprietary) driver. It is fairly easy to set up and it works fine. So far I am happy with it.

I had to enter a password to enroll the key but the password is only relevant for the MOK enrollment, it is discarded and never used again. The user does not hold any secret (like a password) to restrict the usage of the MOK once enrollment is completed.

Apparently, third party driver updates will automatically be signed with the MOK during installation. In other words, an attacker who is able to manipulate my third party driver and therefore to elevate his access rights to the root user will have no difficulty signing the manipulated driver the same way the system updater does.

The only benefits I can think of using secure boot with MOK are:

- It adds some complexity to attack scenarios towards the kernel and drivers by adding an additional check, even though my understanding is that this check is fairly easily bypassed.
- It lets me enable secure boot in the BIOS, which is a security requirement for some operating systems like Windows 11.
- In case secure boot is enabled by default in the BIOS, I don't have to find out how to disable it to make my NVIDIA (proprietary) driver work.

Am I missing something here? Is there any security benefit in using secure boot with MOK on a machine which boots only one operating system?

Comment: With the key stored on an encrypted disk, this protect against evil maid attacks

Comment: Is it possible to move the private key to a secure location? I found https://forums.opensuse.org/t/where-is-everything-mok-related-stored/169720 but it is very vague. It seems to say that the keys will be stored in the UEFI firmware, basically accessible to the operating system without user interaction.

Comment: The public key will be stored in the UEFI firmware. You can even post it on the Internet if you want. The private key is stored somewhere in your drive where dkms can find it. You can move this key to somewhere else but kernel or Nvidia updates installing automatically will fail when signing

Comment: OK thanks for the hint. Is it possible to let DKMS access the key but only with user interaction, for instance by using password based key derivation?

Comment: I've never tried password-protecting the MOK. But if it's not possible, an autofs toward a password protected network share or something FUSE could be a bad workaround.

Comment: I was thinking about your first comment; if the OS partitions are fully encrypted (at least the one which holds the MOK) then this could protect against evil maid attacks? What about my answer below, any comment/suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

[I think I found a similar question on the Unix Stack Exchange.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/535434/what-exactly-is-mok-in-linux-for)

In the answer, the important bits which make sense to me are:

> The main idea is that only code which is signed is allowed to run while loading the operating system (OS). Once that is booted, the OS can take over responsibility from the BIOS for securing the system.

So basically if there is a vulnerability in the OS and an attacker can gain root privileges, a manipulated driver can be executed during the next boot, which is exactly my understanding.

> Do you need MOK and Secure Boot? Not if you will never be successfully attacked by a hacker, especially one who might have physical access to your laptop or gains root access from the Internet through browser/office/Linux bugs.

In my case setting up MOK was fairly easy and adds a little complexity to a potential attack, so I will keep it.